# Collapsing data frame by selecting one row per group

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to collapse a data frame by removing all but one row from each group of rows with identical values in a particular column. In other words, the first row from each group.

For example, I'd like to convert this

```
> d = data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,4),y=c(10,11,12,13),z=c(20,19,18,17))
> d
  x  y  z
1 1 10 20
2 1 11 19
3 2 12 18
4 4 13 17
```

Into this:

```
    x  y  z
1   1 11 19
2   2 12 18
3   4 13 17
```

I'm using aggregate to do this currently, but the performance is unacceptable with more data:

```
> d.ordered = d[order(-d$y),]
> aggregate(d.ordered,by=list(key=d.ordered$x),FUN=function(x){x[1]})
```

I've tried split/unsplit with the same function argument as here, but unsplit complains about duplicate row numbers.

Is rle a possibility? Is there an R idiom to convert rle's length vector into the indices of the rows that start each run, which I can then use to pluck those rows out of the data frame?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Maybe `duplicated()` can help:

```
R> d[ !duplicated(d$x), ]
  x  y  z
1 1 10 20
3 2 12 18
4 4 13 17
R>
```

*Edit*  Shucks, never mind. This picks the first in each block of repetitions, you wanted the last.  So here is another attempt using [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr):

```
R> ddply(d, "x", function(z) tail(z,1))
  x  y  z
1 1 11 19
2 2 12 18
3 4 13 17
R>
```

Here [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr) does the hard work of finding unique subsets, looping over them and applying the supplied function -- which simply returns the last set of observations in a block `z` using `tail(z, 1)`.

Comment: So then you need to simply add a 'processing step' to create a factor variable over which plyr can loop.  It can all be done with indexing commands, give it a try.  And by the way, you are inconsistent between your text (saying first row selected) and example (showing second row).

Comment: By the way, cross-posting between r-help and here is also somewhat poor style. You got good answers at r-help, so why don't you study them?

Comment: My pleasure.  As a matter of common best practices here on StackOverflow, you should accept one post as the solutions (if you feel it provides one) and vote each helpful post up by clicking on the up arrow.  That is how the scoring works here.

Answer (score 14):

Just to add a little to what Dirk provided... `duplicated` has a `fromLast` argument that you can use to select the last row:

```
d[ !duplicated(d$x,fromLast=TRUE), ]
```

Comment: Hi Ian -- unfortunately James never really made a clear case as to whether he wanted first or last and contradicts himself in the post ... but your hint about fromLast is a good one!

Comment: thanks, that works like a charm. Whether its first or last I needed was really up to the ordering, and with fromLast I can attack it either way

Comment: I suggested the same thing and you shot it down on on the grounds of 'prefer all columns'. How come that no longer matters?

Comment: Sorry, Dirk, I misunderstood how duplicated works at the time

Answer (score 14):

Here is a `data.table` solution which will be time and memory efficient for large data sets

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(d)           # convert to data.table
setkey(DT, x)                    # set key to allow binary search using `J()`
DT[J(unique(x)), mult ='last']   # subset out the last row for each x
DT[J(unique(x)), mult ='first']  # if you wanted the first row for each x
```

Comment: But if _all_ that is needed is the last row in each group, then `DT[!duplicated(x,fromLast=TRUE)]` is likely faster than the total time of `setkey` + join, and with some syntactic sugar advantage of avoiding variable name repetition of `DT` (i.e. just `x` not `DT$x`).

Comment: Using the row index would speed things up i geuss, DT[ DT[, .I[.N] , by = x]$V1]. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424762/efficiently-selecting-top-number-of-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-a . Thank to @Simono101

Comment: `unique(DT,by="x",fromLast=TRUE)` is now simpler and faster than `DT[!duplicated(x,fromLast=TRUE)]` and `DT[J(unique(x)), mult ='last']`

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple options using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% distinct(x, .keep_all = TRUE)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% slice(1)
```

You can use more than one column with both `distinct()` and `group_by()`:

```
df %>% distinct(x, y, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

The `group_by()` and `filter()` approach can be useful if there is a date or some other sequential field and 
you want to ensure the most recent observation is kept, and `slice()` is useful if you want to avoid ties:

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(date == max(date)) %>% slice(1)
```

Comment: dplyr::top_n() is also an option see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-the-first-row-by-group/50955051#50955051