# Selecting unique rows in matrix using R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select only the first rows for each unique value of a column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-r)

I have a matrix of the following form:

```
col1 col2

1    2   
1    2    
1    2   
1    2   
1    2
2    5
2    5
2    5
3    7
3    7
3    7
3    7
3    7
3    7
3    7
3    7
4    2 
4    2 
4    2
```

I would like to select all the unique rows based on 'col1'.

which in this case would be the first row from each unique value in col1:

subset:

```
col1   col2
1      2 
2      5
3      7
4      2
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/matrix.csv
mat<-read.csv("matrix.csv")
sub<-unique(mat$V1)
subset(mat, mat==c(sub)
```

It spits out much more than I would expect to get and I get this error mesage:

Warning message:
In contacts$V1 == c(g) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Since this is going to be asked anyway, I'll go first: What have you tried? Is there a particular piece of code you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`unique`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html) function:

```
unique(mat$V1) # and not matrix$v1
[1]   44  281 1312
```

You can also write

```
unique(mat)
```

and it will give you unique lines (I tried it on your file).

If you want to select on `V1`s values, you can do this:

```
> mat[!duplicated(mat$V1), ]
       X   V1 V2 V3 V4  V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1547   44 14  1  2 100 17  0  0  0   0
23  5385  281 67  2 10 100 10  0  0  0   0
33 17347 1312  1  2  6 100  8  0  0  0   0
```

Comment: that will not work, see above

Comment: @user1723765.  It would work if you had a matrix like you said you had.  It turns out that you have a data.frame.   Try `unique(as.matrix(mat))`

Comment: this only selects unique values form the first column, but I want the whole row selected for each unique case

Comment: @user1723765 Yes it does, with `mat$v1` not `matrix$V1`, I used your file.

Comment: unique must be call with MARGIN = 1