# Keep first occurrence of rows irrespective of column of each element

Tags: r

Is there a function that treats the elements of a row as set and returns only the first occurrence of each unique set?

In example below, rows 1 and 3 should be considered equal. It should be irrelevant for the function `foo` whether an element is in `col1` or `col2`.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c('a', 'b', '1'), col2 = c('1', '2', 'a'))


foo(df)

>   col1 col2
> 1    a    1
> 2    b    2
```

Comment: Have you tried unique(df) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843586/selecting-unique-rows-in-matrix-using-r

Comment: unique returns all three rows, not only the first two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this..

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df,1,sort))),]

  col1 col2
1    a    1
2    b    2
```

It sorts each row (so that `a-1` and `1-a` end up the same), and then selects only those rows of `df` that are not duplicates.