# Filter duplicated rows in R data.frame

Tags: r, filter, data.table, dplyr

I  have a data.frame as shown below.

```
> df2 <- data.frame("StudentId" = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3), "Subject" = c("Maths", "Maths", "English","Maths", "English", "Science", "Science"), "Score" = c(100,90,80,70, 60,20,10))
> df2
  StudentId Subject Score
1         1   Maths   100
2         1   Maths    90
3         1 English    80
4         2   Maths    70
5         2 English    60
6         3 Science    20
7         3 Science    10
```

Few StudentIds, have duplicated values for column Subject (example: ID 1 has 2 entries for "Maths". I need to keep only the first one of the duplicated rows.
The expected data.frame is:

```
  StudentId Subject Score
1         1   Maths   100
3         1 English    80
4         2   Maths    70
5         2 English    60
6         3 Science    20
```

I am not able to do this.
Any ideas.

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicate-rows-in-r) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can either use `unique` from `data.table` with the `by` option after converting to 'data.table' (`setDT(df2)`)

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df2), by = c("StudentId", "Subject"))
#   StudentId Subject Score
#1:         1   Maths   100
#2:         1 English    80
#3:         2   Maths    70
#4:         2 English    60
#5:         3 Science    20
```

---

Or `distinct` from 'df2'

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df2, StudentId, Subject)
#     StudentId Subject Score
#       (dbl)  (fctr) (dbl)
#1         1   Maths   100
#2         1 English    80
#3         2   Maths    70
#4         2 English    60
#5         3 Science    20
```

---

Or `duplicated` from `base R`

```
df2[!duplicated(df2[1:2]),]
```

EDIT: Based on suggestions by @David Arenburg)

Comment: I think just `unique(setDT(df2), by = c("StudentId", "Subject"))`? or `distinct(df2, StudentId, Subject)`?