# Remove everything but the first rows from a subset R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have  a large dataset which I want remove all the rows except for the first 8 per value of 1 variable. (in this example only the first one)

example set:

```
   Time <- c(1:20)
    stimulus <- c(rep("happy 1",4),rep("happy 2",4),rep("disgust 1",4),rep("anger 1",4),rep("sad 1",4))
    Happy <- c(runif(20,0,1))
    Disgust <- c(runif(20,0,1))
    Anger <- c(runif(20,0,1))
    Subj1<- data.frame(Time,stimulus,Happy,Disgust,Anger)
```

SO: I want to remove all rows except for Subj1$stimulus 1st row of "happy 1", "happy 2", "disgust 1" etc.
I manage to do so by subsetting to a new variable and then de-selecting everything but the first 8 rows using the following code:

```
Stim1<-which(Subj1$stimulus=="happy 1")
Subj1<- Subj1[-c(Stim1[2:length(Stim1)]),]
```

However, I want to automatically run this for all stimulus variables. Another thing that makes this more difficult is that the row numbers jump because of the removal of rows.

Comment: You say you want to remove all rows "except for the first 8..." yet your example removes all except for the first ONE. What do you mean?

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to remove the first row per each 'stimulus', one option with `data.table` would be to convert to `data.table` (`setDT(Subj1)`), grouped by 'stimulus', we remove the first observation with `tail`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Subj1)[, tail(.SD,-1), by = stimulus]
```

Or if we need only the first observation, use `head`

```
setDT(Subj1)[, head(.SD,1), by = stimulus]
#   stimulus Time     Happy     Disgust     Anger
#1:   happy 1    1 0.2721827 0.263906233 0.3218399
#2:   happy 2    5 0.6649942 0.006288805 0.4758943
#3: disgust 1    9 0.4102272 0.275845885 0.6631558
#4:   anger 1   13 0.2924157 0.776806617 0.8609168
#5:     sad 1   17 0.1599896 0.010758160 0.6081846
```

---

Or another option is `unique` from `data.table` with the `by` option.

```
unique(setDT(Subj1), by = "stimulus")
#   Time  stimulus     Happy     Disgust     Anger
#1:    1   happy 1 0.2721827 0.263906233 0.3218399
#2:    5   happy 2 0.6649942 0.006288805 0.4758943
#3:    9 disgust 1 0.4102272 0.275845885 0.6631558
#4:   13   anger 1 0.2924157 0.776806617 0.8609168
#5:   17     sad 1 0.1599896 0.010758160 0.6081846
```

---

A `dplyr` option would be to group by 'stimulus' and get the first observation with `slice`.

```
library(dplyr)
Subj1 %>% 
     group_by(stimulus) %>% 
     slice(1)
```

---

Or use `ave` from `base R`

```
Subj1[with(Subj1, ave(seq_along(stimulus), stimulus, FUN = seq_along)==1),]
```

Comment: I like the dplyr option, but doesn't OP ask for the first 8 rows? So, slice(8)?

Comment: Yes, but for the example it was 1

Comment: @J.Jansen  What is wrong with my solutions?  I posted it first and have base R options as well.

Comment: @akrun apologies, I used the solution above and it worked since I am not that used to using data.tables. However, I especially think the dplyr method is very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the base R function `duplicated` to keep the first instance of a stimulus level:

```
newdf <- Subj1[!duplicated(Subj1$stimulus), ]
```

I had to make sure that stimulus was not a factor, using stringsAsFactors = FALSE

**data**

```
Subj1<- data.frame(Time,stimulus,Happy,Disgust,Anger, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If your data.frame is ordered by stimulus, and you want to keep the first m observations of each, you could use `which` with `duplicated` as follows:

```
# get rows to include
myRows <- c(sapply(which(duplicated(Subj1$stimulus)), function(i) i:(i+2)))
# subset
newdf <- Subj1[myRows, ]
```

The code above will select the first three observations of each stimulus level. Note as one drawback that it will not check that there are enough observations in a stimulus level.

However,you can perform this check using `table(Subj1$stimulus)`.