# Extract all rows containing first value for each unique value of another column

Tags: r, subset, sqldf

I am looking for something similar to this [Select only the first rows for each unique value of a column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-r)
but I need to keep ALL rows containing the first values of year per ID. 
 In ither words, I need to subset the dataset on the first year listed, by individual ID. IDs can have their first
  year in 1 2 or 3, and all of the rows in the first year should be retained.
  For example:

```
  ID <- c("54V", "54V", "54V", "54V", "56V", "56V", "56V", "59V", "59V", "59V")
  yr <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
  test <- data.frame(ID,yr)
  test

    ID yr
1  54V  1
2  54V  1
3  54V  1
4  54V  2
5  56V  2
6  56V  2
7  56V  3
8  59V  1
9  59V  2
10 59V  3
```

The expected result:

```
  ID   yr
1 54V   1
2 54V   1
3 54V   1
4 56V   2
5 56V   2
6 59V   1
```

My dataset has many columns and I need to retain them all.
Any directions with R or sqldf in R are helpful!

Comment: Another dplyr option: `semi_join(test, distinct(test, ID, .keep_all = TRUE), by = c("ID", "yr"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(yr==first(yr))
#   ID    yr
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1    54V     1
#2    54V     1
#3    54V     1
#4    56V     2
#5    56V     2
#6    59V     1
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, .SD[yr==yr[1L]], ID]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
test[with(test, as.logical(ave(yr, ID, FUN = function(x) x==x[1L]))),]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, fast and functional answer as usual!