# Extract all rows containing second unique value for each column by group

Tags: r, plyr

This is directly related to the question asked in 
[Extract all rows containing first value for each unique value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551449/extract-all-rows-containing-first-value-for-each-unique-value-of-another-column)

but instead of returning the first year an ID was detected, I want to return all rows with only the second year.

Adapting the answers in the above thread from

```
test

    ID yr
1  54V  1
2  54V  1
3  54V  1
4  54V  2
5  54V  2
6  56V  2
7  56V  2
8  56V  3
9  59V  1
10 59V  2
11 59V  3
```

to

```
    test2 <- test[with(test, as.logical(ave(yr, ID, FUN = function(x) x==x[2L]))),]
         or
    test2 <- setDT(test)[, .SD[yr==yr[2L]], ID]
```

produces strange results.

```
   ID yr
1 54V  1
2 54V  1
3 54V  1
5 56V  2
6 56V  2
9 59V  2
```

My desired result would be

```
    ID yr
4  54V  2
5  54V  2
8  56V  3
10 59V  2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 subset(test,as.logical(ave(yr,ID,FUN=function(x)x==unique(x)[2]))) 
  ID yr
1 54V  2
2 54V  2
3 56V  3
4 59V  2

 library(data.table)
 setDT(test)[,.SD[yr==unique(yr)[2]],by=ID]
    ID V1
1: 54V  2
2: 54V  2
3: 56V  3
4: 59V  2

test%>%group_by(ID)%>%filter(yr==unique(yr)[2])
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID    yy
  <chr> <int>
1   54V     2
2   54V     2
3   56V     3
4   59V     2
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I return ALL rows containing the second occurance, and not the unique? Say if 54V would have two years with yr 2.

Comment: In that case the results wont match the desired output

Comment: No, because of the example in this instance, but referring to the first question, it should be clear that I would need all rows, and not unique. I will have to change my example. Big thank you for the answer though.

Comment: Thank you, I can accept this as this answers the direct question in the post. But as my data set has many columns and I need to retain them all, as said in the previous post that I refer to, do you have any ideas how you can adapt the above code for that?

Comment: try the data.table one for your dataset it is eddited