# Remove partially identical rows in dplyr

Tags: dplyr

A simple problem I can't seem to figure out!

```
> ID = c(1, 1, 2)
> var = c("A", NA, NA)
> d <- data.frame(ID, var)
> d
  ID  var
1  1    A
2  1 <NA>
3  2 <NA>
```

What I want to be able to do is remove the 2nd row using dplyr, based on the fact that there is a row with the same ID that has a value for var. If there is only a single ID, I don't want to remove it.

Comment: One of these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-the-first-row-by-group

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select the first row by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-the-first-row-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

How about grouping by `ID` and select the first value arranged so that NA is never selected if there is avlue in that group?

```
ID = c(1, 1, 2)
var = c("A", NA, NA)
d <- data.frame(ID, var)

d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange() %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Results in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID var  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     2 NA
```