# For each unique ID, I would like to have only one row based on a ranking of another field

Tags: r, match, unique, ranking-functions

Ultimately, I am looking to create a table that contains each unique ID I have in my dataset with a corresponding field, based on a "ranking" of that field.

I've been very stuck on this step. I have considered looping for each unique ID, but wanted to see if there was an easier way. Perhaps the apply family of functions could be of help. I'm also not sure of a way to rank different string values (e.g., TRUE > FALSE > NA).

Below is a small sample of what I'm looking at, with just the two fields of interest:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,7), flag = c("NA", "TRUE", "NA", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "NA", "NA", "NA", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE"))
```

For each ID:

- If there is at least one "TRUE" in the flag field, I want to pull one of those entire rows (doesn't matter which one).
- If an ID doesn't contain a "TRUE" value in the flag field, but has a "FALSE" in at least one row, I want to pull one of those entire rows.
- If an ID does not have a "TRUE" or "FALSE" value in the flag field, I still want one of the "NA" rows.

Below is the separate dataframe that I would ideally like to have:

```r
ideal.df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), flag = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "NA", "NA", "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-the-first-row-by-group

Comment: I apologize if this is a duplicate question - I was having trouble conceptualizing the issue, so it very well could be. But the answer @Ronak-Shah provided is exactly what I needed and looks quite different from the answer to the question you've linked to.

Comment: It's okay.  It is one of those questions that we get the first row of each group.   I thought it as a dupe.  Normally, it would be and would be closed,  Since, it is reopened due to a simple technicality, I undeleted my earlier posted answer with a modified one.

Comment: @akrun - Thanks for clarifying

Comment: No problem.  Please note that dupe tagging is not considered a bad thing.  it makes it easier to find a similar post in the future.  So, I am just doing a good samaritan service to SO and all the other people who search for a similar post in the future,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to convert the `flag` variable to ordered factor and get the maximum value from each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(flag = factor(flag, levels = c("NA", "TRUE", "FALSE"), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(flag))

#     ID flag 
#  <dbl> <ord>
#1     1 TRUE 
#2     2 FALSE
#3     3 FALSE
#4     4 NA   
#5     5 NA   
#6     6 TRUE 
#7     7 FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to use `slice` with `match`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   slice(which.max(match(flag, c("NA", "TRUE", "FALSE"))))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   ID [7]
#     ID flag 
#  <dbl> <fct>
#1     1 TRUE 
#2     2 FALSE
#3     3 FALSE
#4     4 NA   
#5     5 NA   
#6     6 TRUE 
#7     7 FALSE
```

---

Or using `rank` with `which.min` on the `logical` 'flag' column

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   slice(which.min(rank(as.logical(flag)) ))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   ID [7]
#     ID flag 
#  <dbl> <fct>
#1     1 TRUE 
#2     2 FALSE
#3     3 FALSE
#4     4 NA   
#5     5 NA   
#6     6 TRUE 
#7     7 FALSE
```