# R: How to keep the first row of each group ordered by some variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame

```r
df = data.frame(
  a = sample(letters, 100, replace=T), 
  b = runif(100),
  d = runif(100)
)
```

And I want to find the first element of each row grouped by `a` and ordered by `b`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  slice(which.min(b))
` ?

Comment: plenty of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13279582/4550695 sort by `b` first and then apply those