# Conditionally remove rows that match in column A, based on column B in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Trying to fix a de-duplication problem using data.table in R.

Column A is a list of names, some of which appear multiple times. Column B is a list of dates. There are a bunch of other columns that I want to copy over as well (things that happened to Name on Date.)

However I only want to look at the most activity for each person in a new datatable which has 1 entry for each name that corresponds to the most recent date.

The example data

```
    name.last       date
 1:     Adams 2014-10-20
 2:     Adams 2014-07-07
 3:   Barnett 2014-11-06
 4:   Barnett 2014-09-22
 5:      Bell 2014-10-22
 6:      Bell 2014-07-29
 7:     Burns 2014-09-08
 8:     Burns 2014-09-03
 9:   Camacho 2014-08-12
10:   Camacho 2014-07-08
11:  Casillas 2014-10-07
12:  Casillas 2014-07-17
13:    Chavez 2014-09-23
14:    Chavez 2014-09-17
15:   Chavira 2014-07-15
16:   Chavira 2014-07-07
17:    Claren 2014-10-30
18:    Claren 2014-10-23
19:  Colleary 2014-11-11
20:  Colleary 2014-11-07
```

The answer would return only the first of each name (since here the rows are sorted with the most recent date for each first.) However if I set the dt key `setkey(dt,name.last)` in order to use `unique()` to remove duplicates, it reorders the table in key order (alphabetical on the names). The use of `unique(dt)` then returns the first appearance of each name which is not necessarily the most recent date.

If I set the key over both columns `setkeyv(dt,c(name.last,date))` I cannot then remove duplicates using `unique()` as all keys are unique.

The problem is similar to the one post here: [Collapsing data frame by selecting one row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626567/collapsing-data-frame-by-selecting-one-row-per-group) . However I cannot assume the data to be selected is first or last unless you can suggest a way to manipulate my data to make it so after setting the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of ways of doing this without ordering the data table (though ordering is preferred because `duplicated` is very efficient and you are also avoiding of using `by` - will get to that).

First of all, you have to make sure that `date` is of class `Date` in order to make things easier

```
dt[, date := as.Date(date)]
```

First simple method (though not the most efficient)

```
dt[, max(date), name.last]
#     name.last         V1
#  1:     Adams 2014-10-20
#  2:   Barnett 2014-11-06
#  3:      Bell 2014-10-22
#  4:     Burns 2014-09-08
#  5:   Camacho 2014-08-12
#  6:  Casillas 2014-10-07
#  7:    Chavez 2014-09-23
#  8:   Chavira 2014-07-15
#  9:    Claren 2014-10-30
# 10:  Colleary 2014-11-11
```

Second (proffered) method is similar to yours but is using data.tables `setorder` (for `data.table` version >= 1.9.4)  and should be the most efficient

```
setorder(dt, name.last, -date)[!duplicated(name.last)]
#     name.last       date
#  1:     Adams 2014-10-20
#  2:   Barnett 2014-11-06
#  3:      Bell 2014-10-22
#  4:     Burns 2014-09-08
#  5:   Camacho 2014-08-12
#  6:  Casillas 2014-10-07
#  7:    Chavez 2014-09-23
#  8:   Chavira 2014-07-15
#  9:    Claren 2014-10-30
# 10:  Colleary 2014-11-11
```

You could achieve the same using `setkey` (as you already did) ans specifying `from.last = TRUE` in `duplicated` and removing `!`

```
setkey(dt, name.last, date)[duplicated(name.last, from.last = TRUE)]

#     name.last       date
#  1:     Adams 2014-10-20
#  2:   Barnett 2014-11-06
#  3:      Bell 2014-10-22
#  4:     Burns 2014-09-08
#  5:   Camacho 2014-08-12
#  6:  Casillas 2014-10-07
#  7:    Chavez 2014-09-23
#  8:   Chavira 2014-07-15
#  9:    Claren 2014-10-30
# 10:  Colleary 2014-11-11
```

Third method is using `data.table`s `unique` function (which should be very efficient too)

```
unique(setorder(dt, name.last, -date), by = "name.last")
#     name.last       date
#  1:     Adams 2014-10-20
#  2:   Barnett 2014-11-06
#  3:      Bell 2014-10-22
#  4:     Burns 2014-09-08
#  5:   Camacho 2014-08-12
#  6:  Casillas 2014-10-07
#  7:    Chavez 2014-09-23
#  8:   Chavira 2014-07-15
#  9:    Claren 2014-10-30
# 10:  Colleary 2014-11-11
```

Last method is using `.SD`. It is the least efficient, but is useful in some cases when you want to get all the column in return and you can't use functions such a s`duplicated`

```
setorder(dt, name.last, -date)[, .SD[1], name.last]
#     name.last       date
#  1:     Adams 2014-10-20
#  2:   Barnett 2014-11-06
#  3:      Bell 2014-10-22
#  4:     Burns 2014-09-08
#  5:   Camacho 2014-08-12
#  6:  Casillas 2014-10-07
#  7:    Chavez 2014-09-23
#  8:   Chavira 2014-07-15
#  9:    Claren 2014-10-30
# 10:  Colleary 2014-11-11
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question, I think you can do this more cleanly with the sqldf package, but the downside is that you have to know sql.

```
install.packages("sqldf")
library("sqldf")
dt <-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = " name.last       date
1:     Adams 2014-10-20
2:     Adams 2014-07-07
3:   Barnett 2014-11-06
4:   Barnett 2014-09-22
5:      Bell 2014-10-22
6:      Bell 2014-07-29
7:     Burns 2014-09-08
8:     Burns 2014-09-03
9:   Camacho 2014-08-12
10:   Camacho 2014-07-08
11:  Casillas 2014-10-07
12:  Casillas 2014-07-17
13:    Chavez 2014-09-23
14:    Chavez 2014-09-17
15:   Chavira 2014-07-15
16:   Chavira 2014-07-07
17:    Claren 2014-10-30
18:    Claren 2014-10-23
19:  Colleary 2014-11-11
20:  Colleary 2014-11-07")
)
head(dt)
colnames(dt) <- c('names', 'date')
sqldf("select names, min(date), max(date) from dt group by names")
```

Hopefully this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In writing this up I figured it out. For posterity....

Order the table by name and date so that you can depend on the date you want being first or last in the group. For example: `dt[order(names,-date)]`.

Then rather than setting a key and using `unique()`, just a simple:

`dt[!duplicated(names)]`

Where `names` is the duplicated column.

Should output the desired table. If there are more elegant / reliable ways to do this I'd be interested in hearing them.