# Remove Duplicates by Unique Value in another Column

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  COLA       COLB     COLC
    A         nb       1
    A         nc       0.8
    A         bc       0.7
    A         nb       0.7  <------------
    B         nb       1
    B         nc       0.3  <------------
    B         nc       0.8
    B         aa       0.9
```

I want to remove the duplicates in COLB by COLA unique ID and keep the maximum value of that duplicate from COLC.

So I want the final result to look like this ( pointed to the rows I want to delete in the previous table):

```
  COLA       COLB     COLC
    A         nb       1
    A         nc       0.8
    A         bc       0.7
    B         nb       1
    B         nc       0.8
    B         aa       0.9
```

Comment: In addition to the one in the dupe tagged, a base R approach is `df1[!duplicated(df1[c(1,3)]),]`

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626567/collapsing-data-frame-by-selecting-one-row-per-group

Comment: How do you extract the maximum value though in column C for that duplicated row in COLA and COLB before removing the duplicates so you remove the correct row? @akrun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  After `arrange`ing the 'COLA", and descendingly the 'COLC', we group by 'COLA', 'COLB' and get the first row with `slice`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(COLA, desc(COLC)) %>% 
   group_by(COLA, COLB) %>% 
   slice(1L)
```